# Returning a JNI array of user defined class

Tags: arrays, java-native-interface, user-defined-types

I have a program that needs to return an array of a user defined structure.  I have the individual structures built and I can immediately extract the data from the structures.  But when I define the array of jobjectArray and do the SetArrayElement of the user defined data types, and then return it to the java calling code java says the array is null.  SetArrayElement does not throw an error but it doesn't have a return value to indicate whether the addition of the element worked.  The GetArraySize returns the length of the jobjectArray that I allocated and not the number of elements that I have added to the array.

Here's an extract of the code:

```
  cipherText = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,
     2,
     myObjectArrayClass,
     tuple);
  if (cipherText == NULL)
     printf("NO NO NO cipherText array is NULL\n");

  printf("add zeroth element to cipherText\n");
  (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,
    cipherText,
    0,
    (jobject)tuple);
  printf("add first element to cipherText\n");
  (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,
    cipherText,
    1,
    (jobject)tuple);
```

Comment: _"it doesn't have a return value to indicate whether the addition of the element worked"_ It throws an exception if setting the element failed, which you should check with `ExceptionCheck` or `ExceptionOccurred`. _"The GetArraySize returns the length of the jobjectArray that I allocated and not the number of elements that I have added to the array."_ I'm not sure I'm following you here. The size of a Java array is fixed after creation, so of course it would return the length you set in `NewObjectArray`, just as if you had written `Object[] cipherText = new Object[2];`

Comment: Show us the function prototypes in Java and C++ and the code where you return the array

Comment: Is `tuple` actually a Java object of type `myObjectArrayClass`? Note that, to satisfy the **`NewObectArray()`** function, this should be the class of the elements of constructed array!

Comment: Here's the java prototype
'code'

package com.voltage.securedata.enterprise;

import com.voltage.securedata.enterprise.mystructs.ZProtectArrayStruct;

public class ZProtect 
{
   public native ZProtectArrayStruct[] arrayProtect(ZProtectArrayStruct[] inTuples);

}

Comment: Here's the class declaration

package com.voltage.securedata.enterprise.mystructs;

public class ZProtectArrayStruct {
    String placeHolder;
    String Cryptid1;
    String Cryptid2;
    String[] data;

    /* constructor */
    public ZProtectArrayStruct(String Cryptid1, String Cryptid2, String[] data)
    {
       this.placeHolder = new String("holder");
       this.Cryptid1 = Cryptid1;
       this.Cryptid2 = Cryptid2;
       this.data = data;
    }
    
...
}

Comment: Here's the C header

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_voltage_securedata_enterprise_ZProtect_arrayProtect
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobjectArray);The function does a 

return ciphertext;

after creating the object array.

Comment: (I'm reading the markdown help, but I haven't figured out how to get these replies to be readable, any help would be appreciated)

Comment: I'm getting an ArrayStoreException attempting to do the SetObjectArrayElement on tuple which is declared as a jobjectArray, into the ciphertext which is declared as a jObjectArray.

the findClass for cipherText used 

char myObjectArrayName[] = "[Ljava/lang/Object;";

Comment: Edit your question. Do not add tons of code in comments.